# Retriving the pods name , the associated images and a label attribute

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I know I can get the pods using:

```
kubectl get pods -n "namespace",  and also to retrieve a json output
```

I'm trying to expand to get the pods name, the associated images, and a label attribute called 'base'. Also the date when I retrieve this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this using yaml output.

`kubectl  get pods --all-namespaces -o yaml| egrep "name:|image:"`

This will give you name of pod and image which is there for running the pod.

**OR**

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}"`

This command will give you all images which are there in all pods.

If you found this is difficult then use,

`kubectl get pod --all-namespaces`

Check which pods image you need to find then use,

`kubectl describe pod <pod_name> -n <namespace>`

For reference use [Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get) you can find the description of `kubectl get` command.
What are you looking for is this:

> `output   o       Output format. One of:
>   json|yaml|wide|name|custom-columns=...|custom-columns-file=...|go-template=...|go-template-file=...|jsonpath=...|jsonpath-file=...`
>   See custom columns
>   [http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/#custom-columns],
>   golang template [http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview]
>   and jsonpath template [http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath].

For example:

> List a pod identified by type and name specified in "pod.yaml" in JSON
>   output format:
>
> `kubectl get -f pod.yaml -o json`

Adjust by using the flags that you need from there.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jsonpath to retrieve the values for json output.

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[0].image}{"\t"}{.metadata.labels.k8s-app}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Answer (score -1):

probably you can write shell script and achieve this. first try to get all running pods across all namespaces using:

`kubectl get pods -all-namespaces`

and then iterate over each pod and execute following command:

`kubectl describe pods <name of pod>`

In the describe command you can get all information that you are looking for.